# Plotly Dash figure/graph/callback: Where do I go from here?

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard

I get the following error, and looking at my code I can't figure out why?

I've tried applying `to_json`/`to_dict('records')` to my **return fig** object but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated...

*dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `<Output` bar_line_1.figure`>`
returned a value having type `Figure`
which is not JSON serializable.
......
...
.
The value in question is either the only value returned,
or is in the top level of the returned list,
........
...
.
In general, Dash properties can only be
dash components, strings, dictionaries, numbers, None,
or lists of those.*

````
@app.callback(
    Output('bar_line_1', 'figure'),
    [Input('region', 'value')],
    [Input('countries', 'value')],
    [Input('select_years', 'value')]
    )
def update_graph(region, countries, select_years):
    mask = (
        (data['Region'] == region)
        & (data['Country'] == countries)
        & (data['Year'] >= select_years[0])
        & (data['Year'] <= select_years[1])
    )
    
    filtered_data = data.loc[mask, :]

    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{'secondary_y': True}]])

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=filtered_data['Year'],
            y=filtered_data['GDP'],
            name='GDP'
        ),
        secondary_y=False,
    )

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=filtered_data['Year'],
            y=filtered_data['FDI'],
            name='FDI'
        ),
        secondary_y=True
    )
    
    return fig```
````

Comment: Is the component with `id='bar_line_1'` a `dcc.Graph()` component?

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino thanks for the reply. I found out what it is.

The problem came from a different .py file I used to clean my api data before importing it into my main.py. One column (Year) had changed into an object type when it was meant to be an integer, I'd been trying to find the error for days. 

Converting with the df['Year'].astype(int) resolved the issue and the graph is working through the callback with no change needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from a different **.py** file I used to clean my api data before importing it into my **main.py**.

One column (Year) had changed into an object type when it was meant to be an integer, I'd been trying to find the error for days.

Converting with the `df['Year'].astype(int)` resolved the issue and the graph is working through the callback with no change needed.